# BeautifulSoup and scraping href's isn't working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Again I am having trouble scraping href's in BeautifulSoup. I have a list of pages that I am scraping and I have the data but I can't seem to get the hrefs even when I use various codes that work in other scripts.

So here is the code and my data will be below that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open('states_names.csv', 'r') as reader:
    states = [states.strip().replace(' ', '-') for states in reader]


url = 'https://www.hauntedplaces.org/state/alabama'

for state in states:
    page = requests.get(url+state)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.findAll('div', class_='description')
    # When I try to add .get('href') I get a traceback error. Am I trying to scrape the href too early? 
    h_page = soup.findAll('h3')

<h3><a href="https://www.hauntedplaces.org/item/gaines-ridge-dinner-club/">Gaines Ridge Dinner Club</a></h3>
<h3><a href="https://www.hauntedplaces.org/item/purifoy-lipscomb-house/">Purifoy-Lipscomb House</a></h3>
<h3><a href="https://www.hauntedplaces.org/item/kate-shepard-house-bed-and-breakfast/">Kate Shepard House Bed and Breakfast</a></h3>
<h3><a href="https://www.hauntedplaces.org/item/cedarhurst-mansion/">Cedarhurst Mansion</a></h3>
<h3><a href="https://www.hauntedplaces.org/item/crybaby-bridge/">Crybaby Bridge</a></h3>
<h3><a href="https://www.hauntedplaces.org/item/gaineswood-plantation/">Gaineswood Plantation</a></h3>
<h3><a href="https://www.hauntedplaces.org/item/mountain-view-hospital/">Mountain View Hospital</a></h3>
```

Comment: You need the all the links in the page or just within in the descriptions?

Comment: Just within the description

Comment: See update on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.hauntedplaces.org/state/Alabama'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for link in soup.select('div.description a'):
    print(link['href'])
```

Comment: By using lxml, does that allow to use the select method, ‘div.description a’?

Comment: No 'html.parser' will do too. It is just better and faster.

Comment: It works great! Thanks and hey sorry I didn't do it faster. I was driving around town grabbing lunch.

Comment: No problem. I am really glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
list0 = []   
possible_links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in possible_links:
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print (link.attrs['href'])
        list0.append(link.attrs['href'])
print(list0)
```